# Syntax highlighting for ES2015 (ES6)

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The syntax highlighting for JavaScript (`lang-js`) is not highlighting [es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) code properly.

For instance, unlike `var`, the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is not highlighted. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) appear to be unrecognized and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) are not highlighted at all let alone the placeholder expressions inside.

Is this something that can be implemented in StackOverflow (and Stack Exchange overall, wherever syntax highlighting is supported), possibly with an upgrade of the syntax highlighting library (I assume)?

Comment: This was closed as a dupe of the generic syntax highlight question, which doesn't seem to address it at all? es6 still seems to not highlight properly today, a year later...

Comment: `Template literals` (`Template strings` before) are still not correctly hightlighted.

Comment: Using `lang-es6` code seems to work