# Backtick string literals not respected when they contain // in JavaScript code blocks

Tags: bug, code-formatting

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259957/1075247) I have a code block like so:

```
edit.replace(vscode.Uri.parse(`file://${path}`), new vscode.Range(start, end), text);
```

When the formatter reads the line and realises it's JavaScript code, everything after `\\` is treated as a comment and not 'escaped' in the backtick literal.

Could the formatting be updated to fix this?

Comment: If you manually set the language for the code block by prefacing it with the line `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, it should remove the syntax highlighting entirely. Does this work around work for you?  Because I think we get our syntax highlighting rules from an external project (I want to say it's Google Prettify), so it's not something we could modify directly as far as I know.

Comment: See the duplicate, the FAQ post on syntax highlighting: bugs need to be reported to the Prettify project.

Comment: Better dupe targets: [Add support for template literals to the JavaScript syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367096/4642212) or [Syntax highlighting for ES2015 (ES6)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311720/4642212).